# Simplify a calc/excel formula with If / And

Tags: excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

How could I make that simplier:

`IF(AND(C$36>140;D$36>140;E$36>140);"OK";IF(AND(D$36>140;E$36>140;F$36>140);"OK";IF(AND(E$36>140;F$36>140;G$36>140);"OK";IF(AND(F$36>140;G$36>140;H$36>140);"OK";"NO"))))`

This formula is in I38.

The idea is to check if in the 6 cells before (on line 36), 3 in-a-row are above 140. So the cells from C36 to H36.

I'm wondering if that is possible to make that simplier/prettier. And also so that ii is to replicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula can be shortened with [COUNTIF](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_COUNTIF_function). Also, separate formulas make it easier to read.

Enter `=COUNTIF(C36:E36;">140")` in cell `E37` and then drag right to fill through `H37`.

Set `I38` to `=IF(COUNTIF(E37:H37;"=3");"OK";"NO")`.

**EDIT**:

The first formula checks each set of 3 cells in a row to see how many numbers in the set are over 140. The second formula checks if any of the results are equal to 3. If so, then there is at least one set where 3 out of 3 are over 140.

Combining this into one formula would look like this:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(C36:E36;">140")=3;COUNTIF(D36:F36;">140")=3;COUNTIF(E36:G36;">140")=3;COUNTIF(F36:H36;">140")=3);"OK";"NO")
```

Or this:

```
=IF(MAX(COUNTIF(C36:E36;">140");COUNTIF(D36:F36;">140");COUNTIF(E36:G36;">140");COUNTIF(F36:H36;">140"))=3;"OK";"NO")
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the "=3" part. How does that check if 3 columns in-a-row are above 140 ?? It just check, if I'm not mistaken, that 3 columns out of the 6 previous ones are above 140

Comment: @meaz: It does the same as your original formula. I added an explanation, although it may be easier to simply follow the instructions and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea for making this formula, however you can improve it a bit, by using a combination of `OR` and `MIN` functions.

Try This:

```
=IF(OR(MIN($C$1:$E$1)>140,MIN($D$1:$F$1)>140,MIN($E$1:$G$1)>140,MIN($F$1:$H$1)>140),"ok","No")
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. `,` should be replaced by `;` though.

Comment: Commas may work in LibreOffice depending on the locale setting. However, semicolons work in any locale, so IMHO they should always be used when posting online solutions for LibreOffice. The counter-argument is that commas work for MS Excel, unlike semicolons, and your question does have an Excel tag. Perhaps you intended the tag to be "spreadsheet formula" instead though.